# How to query by unique attribute with Django-Rest-Framework (Many To Many)

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a simple many to many relationship outlined below:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    """
    just stores a Client hostname now
    """
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        """
        """
        return str(self.hostname)

class Run(models.Model):
    clients = models.ManyToManyField(Client)
```

Using django-rest-framework I now have filters working to identify a specific client:

"/api/runs/?clients=1" works and retrieves all of the runs with the client with primary key of 1.

How can I enable a filter that would allow "/api/runs/?clients=myhostname" ?

Comment: This turned out to be the solution: http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering.html#filtering-against-query-parameters

Answer (score 2):

The answer is below.

In short you must overwrite the get_queryset method.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
filter(clients__hostname=clients)
```

Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships

Comment: Right, I understand how to do it that way from the ORM, but not how to port that query to the rest framework.

Comment: @ChrisKing, add get_queryset() method to your class instead of self.queryset definition/